# Spring AMQP and ShutdownSignalException

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp

I have an AMQP Project with Spring AMQP. The RabbitMQ Server is not mine, so I have no control over it. When my application starts, it makes a private response queue like this:

```
@Bean(name="myAnonymousResponseQueue")
public Queue myAnonymousResponseQueue() 
{       
    Queue q = myAmqpAdmin().declareQueue();
    return q;
}
```

And I have a SimpleMessageListenerContariner like this:

```
    @Bean 
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer myResponseMessageListenerContainer() 
    {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(myConnectionFactory());
        container.setQueues(myAnonymousResponseQueue());
        container.setMessageListener(myRabbitTemplate());
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setMessageConverter(myMessageConverter());
        container.setErrorHandler(myResponseErrorHandler());
        container.setAutoStartup(true);
        container.setRabbitAdmin(myAmqpAdmin());
        return container;
    }
```

I've had connection problems lately (ShutdownSignalException). And the problem is that I can not regenerate the private queue.
First, this is the connection error:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:739)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:729)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(Unknown Source)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:538)
    ... 1 more
```

But when the connection has been restored, the private queue can not be recreated:

```
AbstractConnectionFactory.java|291||Created new connection: SimpleConnection@289cc201 [delegate=amqp://USER@XX.XX.XX.XX:50310/sob]

RabbitAdmin.java|442||Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (amq.gen-SLigrYFVMvllGTS5m_3AzQ) durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.

com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'amq.gen-SLigrYFVMvllGTS5m_3AzQ' in vhost 'sob', class-id=50, method-id=10)

BlockingQueueConsumer.java|565||Failed to declare queue:amq.gen-SLigrYFVMvllGTS5m_3AzQ

BlockingQueueConsumer.java|479||Queue declaration failed; retries left=3
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[amq.gen-SLigrYFVMvllGTS5m_3AzQ]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:571)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:470)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1171)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:885)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.queueDeclarePassive(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:383)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor110.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:835)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy94.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:550)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'amq.gen-SLigrYFVMvllGTS5m_3AzQ' in vhost 'sob', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'amq.gen-SLigrYFVMvllGTS5m_3AzQ' in vhost 'sob', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:484)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:321)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:556)
    ... 1 more
```

And at the end I have this:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK, class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:554)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:509)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:503)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.close(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:642)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler$1.run(CachingConnectionFactory.java:946)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So the AMQP connection is OK, but the private queue isn’t.

I do not understand why this happens. How can I obtain more information? Is it possible to recover from this error?

Thanks

---------------- (28/11/2016) -----------

The reason I have the anonymous queue defined this way, is that with:

```
@Bean(name="myAnonymousResponseQueue")
    public Queue myAnonymousResponseQueue() 
    {       
        return new AnonymousQueue(new Base64UrlNamingStrategy("amq.gen-")); 
    }
```

The server does not allow me to create it and I get the following error:

```
|28-11-2016 08:43:13.203|INFO |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin|initialize|RabbitAdmin.java|493||Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (amq.gen-JUYnhLX2SpqNoJT6ioB8GA) durable:false, auto-delete:true, exclusive:true. It will be redeclared if the broker stops and is restarted while the connection factory is alive, but all messages will be lost.
```

---

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'amq.gen-JUYnhLX2SpqNoJT6ioB8GA' in vhost 'sob', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

---

```
|28-11-2016 08:43:13.486|WARN |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer|attemptPassiveDeclarations|BlockingQueueConsumer.java|581||Failed to declare queue:amq.gen-JUYnhLX2SpqNoJT6ioB8GA
|28-11-2016 08:43:13.486|WARN |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer|start|BlockingQueueConsumer.java|495||Queue declaration failed; retries left=3
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[amq.gen-JUYnhLX2SpqNoJT6ioB8GA]
```

---

```
|28-11-2016 08:43:28.868|WARN |org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer|attemptPassiveDeclarations|BlockingQueueConsumer.java|581||Failed to declare queue:amq.gen-JUYnhLX2SpqNoJT6ioB8GA
|28-11-2016 08:43:28.869|ERROR|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|run|SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java|1372||Consumer received fatal exception on startup
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.QueuesNotAvailableException: Cannot prepare queue for listener. Either the queue doesn't exist or the broker will not allow us to use it.
```

So, what is de difference between AmqpAdmin().declareQueue() and AnonymousQueue? Is it posible that the broker does not permit name the queue?

---

Now I think I understand the problema. I think my user can only create queues named “amq.gen-”. If I try with any other name I get:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue '4788a39b-fffe-4eae-b252-8d842234a018' in vhost 'sob' refused for user 'USER', class-id=50, method-id=10)

com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'amq-_zoOEt5jTcqMduGWNyJ4Zg' in vhost 'sob' refused for user 'USER', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

So, If I can use only broker generates queues, and I need to redeclare it in a reconection, what can i do?

Thank you again.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to apply the work-around. I have declared a ConnectionListener with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Connection arg0) 
{
    myResponseMessageListenerContainer.stop();
    String[] colaAnterior = myResponseMessageListenerContainer.getQueueNames();

    Queue q = myAmqpAdmin.declareQueue();
    q.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(myAmqpAdmin);
    q.setShouldDeclare(true);

    myResponseMessageListenerContainer.addQueueNames(q.getName());

    myResponseMessageListenerContainer.removeQueueNames(colaAnterior);
    myResponseMessageListenerContainer.initialize();
    myResponseMessageListenerContainer.start(); 
}
```

But now I have this error:

```
|30-11-2016 10:56:17.312|ERROR|org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer|redeclareElementsIfNecessary|SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java|1116||Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
    org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Listener expects us to be listening on '[amq.gen-Xg5MG5n42ecpoW4-DA198A]'; our queues: [amq.gen-2qRLgfUmMxskshFCi1dzuA]
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:80)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:113)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:553)
        at es.omie.amqp.config.listener.XBIDConnectionListener.onCreate(XBIDConnectionListener.java:57)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:33)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:500)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:474)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:467)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1500(CachingConnectionFactory.java:97)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1084)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1394)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1370)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1346)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:335)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:95)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1278)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Listener expects us to be listening on '[amq.gen-Xg5MG5n42ecpoW4-DA198A]'; our queues: [amq.gen-2qRLgfUmMxskshFCi1dzuA]
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:770)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:550)
        ... 16 more
```

I keep trying, but any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks

**EDIT 2**

Now I have this:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Connection arg0) 
    {
        myResponseMessageListenerContainer.stop();

        String[] colaAnterior = myResponseMessageListenerContainer.getQueueNames();
        Queue q = myAmqpAdmin.declareQueue();

        log.info(" ------ RESPONSE QUEUE -> OLD NAME: " + Arrays.asList(colaAnterior) + " NEW NAME: " + q.getName());

        myResponseMessageListenerContainer.addQueueNames(q.getName());
        myRabbitTemplate.setReplyAddress(q.getName());
        myRabbitTemplate.setQueue(q.getName());

        myResponseMessageListenerContainer.removeQueueNames(colaAnterior);

        myResponseMessageListenerContainer.shutdown();
        myResponseMessageListenerContainer.initialize();
        myResponseMessageListenerContainer.start(); 
    }
```

But the container does not stay with the last defined queue:

```
|30-11-2016 16:32:19.996|INFO |es.omie.amqp.config.listener.XBIDConnectionListener|onCreate|XBIDConnectionListener.java|42|| ------ RESPONSE QUEUE -> OLD NAME: [amq.gen-uTp6TCP66x2AlXUmQzqz8g] NEW NAME: amq.gen-DOwEn8WKz_9ymCBQFiMDNg


com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'amq.gen-uTp6TCP66x2AlXUmQzqz8g' in vhost 'sob', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

I can't see the new queue name.

I can see in the logs the restart of the container before the connection is created:

```
Restarting Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-KYCURTkS4EevXHQtrpYV9Q=amq.gen-uTp6TCP66x2AlXUmQzqz8g}]
```

But not after the start method.

Answer (score 1):

Spring AMQP provides its own `AnonymousQueue` for this reason; its random name will be retained so, when the connection is re-established, the declaration will be re-created. Your code lets the broker name the queue.

However, you should let the `RabbitAdmin` take care of the declaration automatically rather than doing it yourself.

```
@Bean
public Queue myAnonymousResponseQueue() {
    return new AnonymousQueue();
}
```

When the admin (which must also be a `@Bean`) detects the initial connection (or reconnect), it will declare all such queues.

See [Configuring the Broker](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration).

**EDIT**

If your administrator does not allow you to name the queue (you can't use `amq.gen-` as a prefix) you will have to re-declare the broker-generated queue and update the container with the new queue.

Add a `ConnectionListener` to the connection factory; when `onCreate()` is called (because a new connection is established), stop the container, re-declare the queue, update the container's queue to the new name; start the container.

Bear in mind that any messages in the temporary queue will be lost when the connection is dropped.

Since the listener might be called on a container thread, you should hand off this work to another thread; otherwise there will be a delay.

**EDIT2**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableRabbit
public class So40802855Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So40802855Application.class, args);
        Thread.sleep(2000); // wait for reply queue setup
        RabbitTemplate template = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
        System.out.println(template.convertSendAndReceive("test.x", "foo"));
        context.getBean(CachingConnectionFactory.class).resetConnection();
        Thread.sleep(2000); // wait for reply queue setup
        System.out.println(template.convertSendAndReceive("test.x", "bar"));
        context.getBean(RabbitAdmin.class).deleteQueue("test.x");
        context.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(30000);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        connectionFactory.addConnectionListener(listener());
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
        container.setMessageListener(rabbitTemplate(connectionFactory));
        container.setAutoStartup(false);
        container.setDeclarationRetries(0);
        container.setFailedDeclarationRetryInterval(500);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue testX() {
        return new Queue("test.x");
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionListener listener() {
        return new MyConnectionListener();
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "test.x")
    public String listen(String in) {
        return in.toUpperCase();
    }

    public static class MyConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {

        private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyConnectionListener.class);

        @Autowired
        private RabbitTemplate template;

        @Autowired
        private AmqpAdmin admin;

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Connection connection) {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyContainer = applicationContext.getBean("replyContainer",
                    SimpleMessageListenerContainer.class);
            // need to stop/start asynchronously to avoid deadlock
            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
                if (replyContainer.isRunning()) {
                    logger.info("Waiting for the container to stop itself because of missing queue");
                    while (replyContainer.isRunning()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    }
                    logger.info("Container stopped itself because of missing queue");
                }
                Queue queue = this.admin.declareQueue();
                logger.info("Changing queue from " + Arrays.asList(replyContainer.getQueueNames()) + " to "
                        + queue.getName());
                this.template.setReplyAddress(queue.getName());
                replyContainer.setQueues(queue);
                logger.info("Starting container");
                replyContainer.start();
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(Connection connection) {
        }

    }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. The AnonymousQueue does not work for me, and I don’t know why. I don’t have the control of the bróker or the logs, so I don’t know why. I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: You can't use the `amq.gen-` prefix - that is reserved for queues named by the broker itself; the declaration is ignored.

Comment: Thank you gary, now I understand the problem, but I can't solve it. I have edited my question again.

Comment: Thank you gary. I'm trying with the work-around, but I can not get it to work for now. I have updated my question.

Comment: It looks like this container is the response container for a `RabbitTemplate`; you also need to tell the template about the new reply queue via `setReplyAddress()` so he can set in the `replyTo` message property. Also, the `setShouldDeclare()` etc are redundant - the admin can't declare broker-named queues (and doesn't have visibility to your new `Queue` anyway because it's not a bean.

Comment: Thank you again. You are right, it's the response container for a rabbitTemplate. I've tried what you said but does not work. I think I'm quite close, but does not work yet. I have updated (EDIT 2) again my question.

Comment: The container was not designed to use broker-named queues; there's a race condition because the container stops itself when it finds the queue has gone, so if you start before that stop, you lose the container. I worked around it as you can see in my second EDIT above, by waiting for the container to stop itself instead; I also tweaked the config so it stops faster. Have you considered using [Direct ReplyTo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#direct-reply-to)? It's a lot simpler than using a reply container.

Comment: I have tried with Direct ReplyTo but I have no response from the server. I think they are sending the response to the reply-to from the AMQP Message Property (it's in their documentation). I'll try with the work-around of your second EDIT.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Your work-around works perfectly. But I have doubts about if it is the best option. If I need a broker-named queue and it seems that the Direct ReplyTo option does not work, is there any other possibility besides using a SimpleMessageListenerContainer?

Comment: That's how direct reply-to works - the broker sets a special value in the property so it can route the response appropriately. All these solutions use the replyTo property. You can remove the reply container altogether and set `useTemporaryReplyQueues` to true and the template will create (and discard) a new broker-named queue for each request. It's a little less efficient but avoids the issue with flaky connections (although of course you can still lose any messages in-transit when the connection drops).

Comment: I've tried with no replyQueue (or with amq.rabbitmq.reply-to), I've remove the reply container, but when i send a message (getMyRabbitTemplate().sendAndReceive(exchange, routingkey, msg);) I have no response from the server. It's the same with useTemporaryReplyQueues. What can i have wrong?

Comment: I have no idea; sorry; they should all work (and do everywhere else) - you'll need to look at debug logs on both the client and server side.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much Gary.