# Spring AMQP and conmutation between two RabbitMQ servers

Tags: spring-amqp

I have a project in which I use Spring AMQP. I have two SimpleMessageListenerContainer, one with a self-declared queue by the server (amq-gen), and one with a queue with a given name.
I use a SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory with two CachingConnectionFactory. For error detection I have a ConnectionListener, ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent, and a ConditionalExceptionLogger.

The idea is to switch between two Rabbit servers once an error is detected in the AMQP connection, but when there is an error in the AMQP connection several errors are thrown in the ConditionalExceptionLogger, several events of type ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent, and complicates the fact of switching automatically Between servers.

What could be the best way to do that switching automatically given a number of retries?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> one with a self-declared queue by the server (amq-gen)

You can't do that; if you use broker-declared queue names, the second broker doesn't know about it, and the container will try to declare it, which is not allowed.

Instead use a Spring AMQP `AnonymousQueue`, which has the same characteristics as a broker declared queue (auto delete, not durable) but has a name generated by the framework so it can be declared when you fail over.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Gary. I have no choice (remember this conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802855/spring-amqp-and-shutdownsignalexception). I use the trick you told me, and it works by creating a new queue with each new connection. The problem is that the error detection of the connection and the SimpleMessageListenerContainer jump in parallel, and it is difficult to discern when there really is a problem that prevents reconnection and I have to switch to the other server.

Comment: On the container, set `autoDeclare` to `false` and `declarationRetries` to `0` and the container will fail fast and stop itself. You can add an `ApplicationListener` to detect the `AsyncConsumerStoppedEvent`. After you fail over and redeclare the queue, you can update the queue name in the container and restart it.